# complete name not appearing google chart

Tags: css, charts, column-chart

I have a simple problem with the chart that i have created.
Please see the this [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart).

Over here, if you see the 1st example, on right hand side "Motivation Level" label  is not completely appearing and we have to hover over it to read the name.

I would like to display the complete name without hover. I tried adjusting the width of the chart, but it doesn't work, instead it expands the area on the chart.

Any idea how this could be achieved?